# Can't join two temp tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, left-join, sql-null

I've been trying to join two temp tables but I keep getting an error message saying "Ambiguous column name" even though I used column alias. FYI, this is SQL Server programming.

```
select ID, count(PageNum) as Frequency 
into temp_list
from ID_USA
group by ID

select ID, ISNULL(PageNum1,'') +','+ISNULL(PageNum2,'') +','+ISNULL(PageNum3,'') +','+ISNULL(PageNum4,'') +','+ISNULL(PageNum5,'') As PageNum
from temp_table k 
left join temp_list c on c.ID = k.ID
```

The error message says Ambiguous column name 'ID'.

Could anyone please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Column `id` is there in both tables, so an unqualified `id` is ambiguous in the query - you have that in your `select` clause.

Consider prefixing this column with a table alias - since you have a `left join`, I picked the left table:

```
select k.ID, 
    concat_ws(',', c.pageNum1, c.PageNum2, c.pageNum3, c.pageNum4, c.pageNum5) As PageNum
from temp_table k 
left join temp_list c on c.ID = k.ID
```

I also prefixed all `pageNum` columns, based on the assumption that they come from the right table.

Note that I changed the `+` string concatenation to `concat_ws()`: although this does not do *exactly* the same thing as your original expression, this is close enough (and much more concise) to be worth a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no reason to use a temporary table, at least for the first query.

Second, as GMB pointed out, you need qualified column names.

Third, you can use the `concat()` function to exactly replicate your logic more simply (because `concat()` ignores `NULL` values).

So, I would suggest:

```
with temp_list as (
      select ID, count(PageNum) as Frequency 
      from ID_USA
      group by ID
     )
select k.ID,
       concat(c.PageNum1, ',', c.PageNum2, ',', c.PageNum3, ',', c.PageNum4, ',', c.PageNum5) as PageNum
from temp_table k left join
     temp_list c
     on c.ID = k.ID;
```

Note that every column reference in the query is preceded by the table alias.  Such *qualified* column references are never ambiguous.

Of course, you can keep `temp_list` if you need it for other reasons.  But you don't need a temporary table for this query.